# Sharp difference between almost similar meanings

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between "Speculation" & "Propaganda"?

Comment: Do you really think that the two terms have almost similar meaning?

Comment: I have seen people using it interchangeably. May be I am having misconception. Please explain.

Comment: They don't, as far as I know. You should provide examples of the usage you are referring to and check their meanings in a dictionary. Here for instance: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/

Comment: The newspapers are speculating that there can be recession due to sudden collapse of the stock market.                             The newsman is spreading propaganda that a huge recession is surmounting the economy of the nation due to collapse of the share market.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're speculating that they mean the same thing, or you're determined to spread propaganda to that effect.

Comment: I think it is the intention which determines whether the information is speculation or propaganda

Answer (score 2):

**speculation** and **propaganda**

These are not as similar in meaning as you might think. From *Merriam Webster*:

> **speculation**: ideas or guesses about something that is not known

and...

> **propaganda:** ideas or statements that are often false or exaggerated and that are spread in order to help a cause, a political leader, a government, etc.
>
> 2: the spreading of ideas, information, or rumor for the purpose of helping or injuring an institution, a cause, or a person
>   3:  ideas, facts, or allegations spread deliberately to further one's cause or to damage an opposing cause; also :  a public action having such an effect

So you can see that "speculation" is just a supposition, an idea *gathered* without firm knowledge. "Propaganda" is a deliberate attempt to *disseminate* information. There may be truth contained in either practice; speculation may be part of propaganda. You can be honest and open about your *speculation*; as a *propagandist* you probably won't be.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Propaganda](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/propaganda)** - chiefly derogatory Information, especially of a biased or *misleading* nature, used to promote or publicize a particular political cause or point of view
>
> **[Speculation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/speculation?q=Speculation)** - The forming of a theory or conjecture without firm evidence

That being said **speculation** *can* be used for **propaganda** but they are not inherently related.

Comment: Can we say that it is the intention of the propagator which determines that the information that he/she is propagating is speculation or propaganda..?

Comment: So what you are asking is if someone who is openly speculating is also trying to misinform people...deliberately make people confused or plant an idea in their mind?  To propagandize by speculating?

Answer (score 0):

**Propaganda**, *publicity and promotion* are comparable when they mean a systematic effort to mold public opinion in respect to something or the means or the matter used in such an effort.*

> Propaganda is applied to the *concerted or systematic* effort of a
>   group that tries to convert others or to hold others to its way of
>   thinking, and to the means employed and the matter circulated.

The term has chiefly derogatory, but occasionally underogatory use.

- communist propaganda

(MW dictionary of synonyms)

> When you guess about how something is going to come out (or how it
>   happened), that's **speculation**. *You're making an educated guess.*

When people predict who will win a football game, an Oscar, or an election, it's speculation: people are looking at the facts and making their best guess.

- Just about anything you say about the future is **speculation**, because
  no one knows what will happen.

(vocabulary.com)